# Statistical significance changing in hierarchical regression?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multilevel-analysis

What does it mean if, performing hierarchical linear regression, significance of a variable changes? So, in one step, statistical significance of a variable is 0.006, but in the next one (after adding more variables) it is 0.861. Which of these figures should I pay attention to?

Answer (score 1):

Both.

The statistical significance of that variable (say $x_1$) changed/ was attenuated because of information encode in the extra variables you added (say $x_2$ to $x_p$). That information is something of interest. To mention some plausible scenarios:

1. You might have confounding effects between $x_1$ and one (or some) of
   the variables $x_{2, \dots, p}$,
2. You might have just a noise corrupted
   version of the $x_1$ in your newly included variables,
3. You might have
   $x_1$ being the (slightly imperfect) linear combination of some of
   the variables  $x_{2, \dots, p}$,
4. You just might saturated your model
   with the inclusions of the new variables and you run out of degrees
   of freedom.

In any case, both values are of interest at least at the preliminary stage of a regression analysis.